# sql inserr based on maximum date

Tags: database

I have to just insert the value from one table into another but the condition is that out of same id I have to select that one having maximum date and then insert into another. like :

**table 1**

```
a | b

1 | 12/1/13
1 | 18/1/13
2 | 2/4/13 
2 | 9/8/13
```

**table 2**

```
a | b

1 | 18/1/13
2 | 9/8/13
```

please suggest the SQL query for it

Answer (score 0):

Could you try :

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (idcolumn, datecolumn)
SELECT DISTINCT idcolumn, datecolumn
FROM Table1
GROUP BY idcolumn
ORDER BY datecolumn DESC
```

Comment: What happens ? An error or just nothing appear ?
    
Can you try without ORDER BY clause ?

Comment: This will insert the whole table1 into table2, only omitting duplicate _records_. But there are no duplicate records in the example. DISTINCT will see (1, 2/2/13) as different from (1,2/3/13) so include both rows.

Comment: DISTINCT doesn't check only the first column without brackets ? Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2(a,b)
SELECT a, MAX(b) AS b 
FROM table1
GROUP BY a;
```

Comment: This should work, although only on the assumption that those dates are indeed dates and not stored as string (then there is a whole other problem!)